# Excel file missing reference to Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2

Tags: excel, vba

I need to export a .xlsm file to other computers. I'm having trouble with a reference.

For instance: atual_date = Date - is giving error of missing library.

How can I export the file with the references included?
Can I have a individual file that adds the references to the other computers?

[image: https://ibb.co/jGjz77j]

How can I work around?
Why is this refence missing?
Can I add VBA code to paste the mscomct2.ocx file when the user opens the file?

Comment: The workbook it is saved with references checked. There are missing references only if on the new computer the referenced library does not exist. Even if it is a matter of diferite version.

Comment: What is missing is the mscomct2.ocx file. Can you tell me how I can work arround? Why is missing this refence? Can I add some VBA code to paste the mscomct2.ocx file when the user opens the file?

Thank you for answering!

Comment: Do you use this reference (Microsoft Windows Common Controls...) in Excel? It usually is used in Access and if I remember well, it is useless now. Try, please uncheck it and see what happens...

Comment: Wow, that worked! Many thanks! That happens to lack of knowledge of each reference is related to! What I can't explain is why before on this : atual_date = Date , was giving library missing, and now, I unchecked and work. But that is not so important... @FaneDuru, thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: When you have a missing  referenced library, even Left or Right will not work, anymore. The line where the error occurs is not all the time directly related to the missing library... ;)

Comment: I didn't know that. As it was the first time that I was trying the file on a different computer, when appeared the error on the Date, I instantly assumed that should be missing some reference. Luckly it was a lot easier to solve!

Comment: The important issue is that now you know... :)

Comment: Yes always learning! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use this reference (Microsoft Windows Common Controls...) in Excel?

It usually used to be used in Access and if I remember well, it is useless now. Try, please un-checking it and see what happens...

Please, see the next [link](https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/files/cbdb/files/fix_mscomctrl_error_in_access_2018-10.pdf)

And take care to un-check it from the original file, too. Otherwise, it must be removed only after an error will appear...

Comment: It worked! What I don't understand why atual_date = Date was giving "missing library" and now it doesn't. But that doesn't matter anymore. Worked perfectly! Again, thank you very much!!

Comment: @TiagoSantos: Glad I could help! I tried clarifying this issue after your first comment asking for such a clarification. Please, check it...